# R error: Error in as.numeric(apply) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

I have searched the similar questions and could not find an answer that applies to my case. They helped me understand the problem - but I still don't know how to fix it. 
I'm doing an ordinal logistic regression and what I want is a table like this:

```
 ## as.numeric(apply)    N=400
 ## 
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+
 ## |       |           |N  |Y>=0|Y>=1   |Y>=2 |
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+
 ## |bekt   |1          |337|Inf |-0.3783|-2.44|
 ## |       |2...       | 63|Inf | 0.7655|-1.35|
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+ 
 ## |vstt   |1          |343|Inf |-0.2048|-2.35|
 ## |       |2...       | 57|Inf |-0.1759|-1.55|
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+
 ## |verwt  |1          |102|Inf |-0.3973|-2.77|
 ## |       |2          | 99|Inf |-0.2642|-2.30|
 ## |       |3...       |100|Inf |-0.2007|-2.09|
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+
 ## |Overall|           |400|Inf |-0.2007|-2.20|
 ## +-------+-----------+---+----+-------+-----+
```

It displays the (linear) predicted values we would get if we regressed our dependent variable on our predictor variables one at a time, without the parallel slopes assumption.
This is the code I use (and I get the error message above):

```
  sf <- function(y) {
c('Y>=0' = qlogis(mean(y >= 0)),
  'Y>=1' = qlogis(mean(y >= 1)),
  'Y>=2' = qlogis(mean(y >= 2)))
   }

s <- with(dataframe, summary(as.numeric(apply) ~ bekt + vstt + verwt + nwoet, fun=sf))
```

`bekt` etc. are columns in the dataframe.

Comment: At a brief read, this looks like you are trying to convert a function (i.e. apply) to a number (via `as.numeric`) and it's erroring. A simple renaming of your apply column to something else could solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what it is, I think. I just can't seem to change it in a way that corrects it.

Comment: Does something along the lines of Df$newcol <- as. Numeric (Df$apply) ; with(df, summary(newcol....) work? (sorry Typing on phone)

Comment: Thank you! It's not entirely correct yet, but it did produce a table. Code:
`typmed23$newcol <- as.numeric(typmed23$typ)` //
`s <- with(typmed23, summary(typmed23$newcol ~ verw2 + nwoe2, FUN=sf))`
The new table is wrong, the sf function (see above) wasn't applied for some reason. Instead of the 3 columns (see above), I now have 2 called `N` and `typmed23$newcol`.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** *Oh my Gosh, I can't believe it! I just figured out the problem, it's terribly simple: "apply" is not a command in this case. It's a variable, a column in a df that's called "apply". Darn...!*

Answer (score 0):

Your question could do with a bit more explanation as to what you are trying to accomplish i.e. an example of the structure you would expect for you output and what you input looks like.

Having said that, from what I can gather, you want to apply your function `sf` over each column get the `qlogis` results per column per comparator (0, 1, 2)

If that is the case something like this might be what you are looking for:

```
sapply(0:2, function(ref) {qlogis(colMeans(dat >= ref))})
```

It would give out a matrix where each column relates to a reference value (0,1,2) and each row relates to a column.

No need to write the `sf` function.

Hope I've got the right end of the stick,

:)

Comment: Thank you! =) I edited the question as you suggested and I think you're suggesting something close to what I want. When I run your code, it produces a matrix like this (in better shape than this):   
       `[,1]   [,2]      [,3]
typ    Inf   Inf    0.6808771
bekt   Inf  Inf 2.8774684
vstt   Inf  Inf 3.5221500
verwt  Inf  Inf 3.5221500
nwoet  Inf  Inf 2.5917367`

Comment: @jira Is that what you expected? I mean are the Inf values the expected result or do you think that is an error? Are you looking for code to format it into that table? In relation to your original question `apply` is a function so trying to coerce it to numeric is giving you your specific error. Look at the documentation for `apply` for how to call it.

Comment: No, it's not, I feel like there's something wrong with the many Infs. Thanks, yes, I get the problem, but I can't seem to solve it. Whatever changes I make to 
`s <- with(typmed2, summary(as.numeric(apply) ~ bekt + vstt + verwt + nwoet, fun=sf))`, moving "apply" and (), the best I can get is `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`. The R help doesn't help.

Comment: @jira The function argument to apply is called `FUN` not `fun`. It makes a difference.

Comment: Tried it before I commented here, same error message.